# Https connection Java, Android, self-signed certificate, java

Tags: java, ssl, https, sslsocketfactory

I have following source code written in Java, which creates https connection to remote server and makes some request to http server:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.util.*;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.*;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class trustStore {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    char[] password = "OQASNRati6c=".toCharArray();

    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream("lamkin.p12");
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    keystore.load(fIn, password);
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(keystore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1" }, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://172.20.175.1/kani/");
        System.out.println("executeng request" + httpget.getRequestLine());
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        try {

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

        if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println("Response content lingth: " + entity.getContentLength());
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } finally {
        response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
    }
}
```

I try to do same for android platform and i faced with the problem: How to release next strings of code in android app:

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(keystore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1" }, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
```

I haven't found in Android SDK CloseableHttpClient, SSLContexts, SSLConnectionSOcketFactory.
And can anybody tell me what is SSLSocketFactory? Why is it needed?

UPDATE:

I try following lines of code:

```
        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream("lamkin.p12");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(fIn, password);


        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(keyStore, password);

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        URL url = new URL("https://kompot.petrsu.ru/kani/");
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

And it does not work on Ubuntu OS, arise following exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I did same on Android OS and then i get following exception:

```
04-11 11:35:30.123: W/System.err(4880): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
04-11 11:35:30.133: W/System.err(4880):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:401)
04-11 11:35:30.133: W/System.err(4880):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
04-11 11:35:30.133: W/System.err(4880):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:478)
04-11 11:35:30.133: W/System.err(4880):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
etc...
```

In what may be problem?

Comment: What does 'how to release next strings of code' mean?

Comment: Sorry. How to implement next strings of code in adnroid?

Comment: I don't know what a 'string of code' is, but then I've only been programming since 1971. Do you mean *lines* of code? And if so, what's your actual problem?

Comment: I'm sorry , my English is bad :( The problem is what i make https connection under ubuntu(code above), but i can't to do same under android OS, same approach does not work, when i try make get request on server arise exception "Trust anchor for certification path not found", and i don't know what is wrong.

Comment: That bizarre error message means your truststore doesn't trust the server certificate. Is it self-signed?

Comment: Yes, i use self-signed certificate. Please, pay attention, i have updated my post. File lamkin.p12 consist of CA certificate, private certificate and personal private key.